# Ember custom view exception: had no action handler for: searchEvent

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have my custom view :

```js
export default Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  classNames: ['search-terms'],
  eventTypeValue: null,
  userSidValue: null,

  init: function() {
    this._super();

    this.eventTypeValue = Ember.TextField.create();
    this.userSidValue = Ember.TextField.create();

    this.eventTypeValue.set("placeholder", "search by event type");
    this.eventTypeValue.addObserver("value", this.userSidValue, this.change);

    this.userSidValue.set("placeholder", "earch by user sid");
    this.userSidValue.addObserver("value", this.userSidValue, this.change);

    this.pushObject(this.eventTypeValue);
    this.pushObject(this.userSidValue);
  },

  change: function() {
    this.get("controller").send("searchEvent");
  }
});
```

And controller :

```js
export default Em.Controller.extend({

  actions: {
 searchEvent : function() {
  console.log("controller searchEvent");
 }
  }
  
});
```

And when I change text in some fields, then I have following exception:

> Uncaught Error:  had no action handler for: searchEvent

But this working when I type some text and then click somewhere out of my custom view.

Comment: Try se**a**rch instead of serch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the second argument to `addObserver` - this is the context that the third argument (`this.change`) is executed with.

Even though you specify `this.change`  it doesn't use `this` - it uses the `Ember.TextField` as the `this` not the `ContainerView`.

You need to change the following two lines:

```
this.eventTypeValue.addObserver("value", this.userSidValue, this.change);
this.userSidValue.addObserver("value", this.userSidValue, this.change);
```

to:

```
this.eventTypeValue.addObserver("value", this, this.change);
this.userSidValue.addObserver("value", this, this.change);
```

[This is a working JSBin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kamesuneca/1/edit?js,console,output)

I've commonly seen strings passed as the method (the third argument) - this also works. I would pass strings instead of the actual function itself.

```
this.eventTypeValue.addObserver("value", this, 'change');
this.userSidValue.addObserver("value", this, 'change');
```